# Higher variance in sample mean or sample median?

Tags: variance, mean, median

The variance of the sample median depends on the distribution you are sampling from. This is also true for the variance of the mean. But can one say that the variance of the sample mean is always greater than the sample median, or is this also dependent on the distribution we are sampling from?